# Curl PHP как передать в заголовке одновременно json и данные

Tags: php, json, curl

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));`

С помощью CUrl запроса я передаю json, но мне также нужно передать токен(это API запрос),
в обычном случае я бы передал это массивом, но application/json и есть массив. Вопрос: как мне одновременно передать и этот параметр и токен в формате: `"mytoken": $token`

Comment: может токен в хедере выставляется? у Вас есть пример как с консоли сделать то, что Вам нужно?

Comment: В консоле, отправляется несколько заголовков :0

Comment: Вот я и хотел передать массивом, но можно ли в массиве передать ещё одни массив?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно так:

```
$arFields = [
   "name" => 'Иван Иванов',
   "birthday" => '02.02.2002',
   "phone" => '+7(999)99-99-99',
   "sex" => 'Male',
];
$jFields = json_encode($arFields, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

$arOptions = [
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false, //Проверка SSL сертификата
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false, //Проверка хоста на соответствие с SSL
    CURLOPT_HEADER => true, //Включаем передачу заголовка
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, //Возврат результата
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
        'Authorization: Bearer ' . base64_encode($token),
        'Accept: application/json',
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    ], //Массив заголовков
    CURLOPT_URL => $this->url . '/client/' . $id, //Загружаемый URL, куда посылаем
    CURLOPT_POST => true, //Передаем данные POST
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $jFields, //POST - запрос
];
curl_setopt_array($ch, $arOptions);
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Но могу попросить ещё одну просьбу? Обозначьте комментами пожалуйста каждый параметр, я нубик в CUrl) Не совсем всё понятно

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Все параметры для curl_setopt  можно найти здесь:  https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-setopt.php

Comment: Всё, понял как вы реализуете запрос) Большое спасибо ещё раз

Comment: @nikello просто вы передали все параметры в виде массива, это ввёло в ступор

Comment: Зачем отключать проверку ssl?

Comment: @Kotomi Это общий пример для новичков, т.к. пока это проблема для некоторых. Либо его нет на тестовом стенде, либо это Let's Encrypt, у которого с 30 сентября не обновился корневой сертификат

Comment: @nikello единственное у меня возникает вопрос, что такое bearer? И откуда берётся $arFields?

Comment: @artemgh 
Слово «Bearer (Предъявитель)» означает, что у вас есть определенный токен (доступ). Предъявителем является стороннее приложение, которому его выдал провайдер идентификации. Этот токен обеспечивает немедленный доступ к ресурсу, не требуя имени пользователя и пароля. С этим токеном связана вся необходимая информация, включая данные пользователя и объем возможных действий, которые может предпринять третье лицо от имени этого пользователя.

Токен Bearer обычно включается в заголовки GET или POST-запросов к конечной точке API.

Comment: Насчет $arFields правильное замечание, поправил

Comment: А про токены нужно читать в документации к вашему API, к которому выполняете запросы. Может там по другому выполняется аутентификация по токенам

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо